# Site Responsivo com %

Tags: html, css

Bom, a minha dúvida é um bocado abstrata, contudo gostava que me exclarececem alguns aspectos relativamente a Site responsivo.

Gostaria de saber, qual será a forma de um site ficar o melhor possível, para todos os ecrãs. Ou seja, se eu usar '%' em vez de 'px', o site fica a pelo menos 90% responsivo?

Que mais aspectos são relevantes fazer para que o site possa parecer o mais bonito possível para todas as telas.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fica. Um site pode ser feito através da definição dos tamanhos em porcentagem e consertando o que quebrar com as media queries.
Porém, fazer a responsividade de um site através de % acaba sendo um tanto quanto complicado e trabalhoso.
Você precisaria trabalhar cada elemento com um tamanho relativo, pois seria uma porcentagem em relação ao monitor.
Uma das alternativas é utilizar frameworks que já fazem isso para você através de classes, como o Bootstrap, o Wirefy, Skeleton, Less Framework e por aí vai (no fim, esses frameworks utilizam tudo em porcentagem).

Quanto aos aspectos: imagens responsivas, que se adequem ao tamanho da tela, acessibilidade (pensando que o usuário poderá utilizar o toque em uma tela pequena ao invés de um mouse), etc..

Segundo o livro Web Design Responsivo: Páginas adaptáveis para todos os dispositivos, a trinca para a responsividade é:

- Layout fluído: pensar, desde a concepção, em layouts que não tenham tamanho fixo, e que podem ser adaptados, evitando que o conteúdo seja cortado ou crie barras de rolagem;
- Imagens e recursos flexíveis; e
- Media queries: diretivas em que é possível ocultar, fazer aparecer e reposicionar elementos e interações conforme a resolução atual que está sendo usada no momento da visitação. Afinal, um site não precisa (e, na verdade, não deve) ter, exatamente, a mesma aparência e disposição de elementos em qualquer resolução.

Referência: ZEMEL, Tárcio. Web Design Responsivo: páginas adaptáveis para todos os dispositivos. Editora Casa do Código, 2015. [link](https://books.google.com.br/books?hl=pt-BR&lr=&id=82SCCwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=responsivo&ots=tkzk4yoX2-&sig=APnrO1BiZXvc586VdfwMkvJuTAE#v=onepage&q=responsivo&f=false)

Comment: (Bonito ver um livro como referência)

Comment: Hehehe obrigado @Kahler! Creio que um livro acrescente um pouco de credibilidade na resposta...